# In the case of Divisors, how do you define a "sufficiently divisible" integer?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

See the title. Example:

**Theorem (Base Point Freeness Theorem in Dimension 2).**

Let $L$ be a
(rational) divisor on a nonsingular projective surface $S$ of the form
$L = A +rK_S$,
where $A$ is an ample divisor, $r$ a nonnegative rational number.
Assume that $L$ is nef.
Then $|lL|$ is base point free for *sufficiently* (*divisible* and) large $l\in \mathbb N$ (so that
$lL$ is an integral divisor).

Either this was not defined in any of the standard texts I read, or I missed it.

Comment: Sufficiently divisible only to make sure that $lL$ is an integral divisor. So, if $l$ is  a multiple of the denominator of $r$, it is fine and then you want $l$ to be sufficiently large.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.